# Python - Updating dictionary in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I am trying to save my grades by each period in a dictionary

```
for classes in soup.find_all("div", "AssignmentClass"):
    grades = classes.findAll("span")[5]
    periods = classes.findAll("a", "asmt_link")
    final = {}
    for i in grades:
        for x in periods:
            print "%s: %s" % (x.get_text(), i)
            final.update({x.get_text():i})
```

**Result:**

```
Period 1: 97.00000

Period 2: 84.93440

Period 3: 25.83333

Period 4: 86.38029

Period 5: 86.15000

Period 6: 86.87500

Period 7: 66.76380
```

But in the end `final` only has the last period `{'Period 7': 66.76380}`

**What I want:**

```
{'Period 1': 97.00000, 'Period 2': 84.93440, 'Period 3': 25.83333, 'Period 4': 86.38029, 'Period 5': 86.15000, 'Period 6':  86.87500, 'Period 7': 66.76380}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to add each period and grade to the dictionary.

```
final={}  
for classes in soup.find_all("div", "AssignmentClass"):
    grades = classes.findAll("span")[5]
    periods = classes.findAll("a", "asmt_link")
    for p, g in zip(periods, grades):
                final.setdefault(p.get_text(), g)
```

**Result:**

```
{'Period 1': 97.00000, 'Period 2': 84.93440, 'Period 3': 25.83333, 'Period 4': 86.38029, 'Period 5': 86.15000, 'Period 6':  86.87500, 'Period 7': 66.76380}
```

Using **.setdefault()** solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The two inner loops seem wrong, you want to traverse the periods and the grades *simultaneously*, not traversing all the periods for each grade (that's the effect caused by nesting a loop inside another.)

Assuming that there's an equal number of grades and periods the correct way to build a dictionary would be:

```
final = dict(zip((x.get_text() for x in periods), grades))
```

The "long" way to do this (as requested in the comments) would be:

```
final = {}
for period, grade in zip(periods, grades):
    final[period.get_text()] = grade
```

Also notice that at the end you'll only get a dictionary with the periods/grades of the last class, because you're iterating and creating a new dictionary for each class and discarding the previous dictionaries.

Comment: Can you show how it would be written the "long" way? (eg: not using generators or list comprehension). People looking at these python constructs might miss out on what the actual logic is.

Comment: @MxyL I think anyone familiar enough with Python will understand the constructs used...

Comment: How can I create a dictionary with the periods/grades of all classes?

Comment: @JoseRoman and how are you going to differentiate between the classes? because all they are going to have the same periods, so they will overwrite each other if stored in a single dictionary (a dictionary can not have duplicate keys)

Comment: Why are they all going to have the same periods? Sorry for my lack of understanding.

Comment: @JoseRoman tell me: what are the names of the first class' periods? and what are the names of the second class' periods? and so on for all the classes.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Finance, English, Trigonometry, Astronomy, Chemistry, Economics, History.

Comment: @JoseRoman those are the classes' names. I asked you for the names of the periods in each class...

Comment: @ÓscarLópez What do you mean by names of the periods? Period 1: Finance, Period 2: English, Period 3: Trigonometry, Period 4: Astronomy, Period 5: Chemistry, Period 6: Economics, Period 7: History

Comment: So class name and periods are the same thing? ie: `Finance` and `Period 1` both refer to the same thing? You would need to edit in a sample of the output you would like to clarify your requirements.

Comment: @MxyL Yes, they are the same thing.